# How to cut a piece of 2x3 wood crossways perfectly?

Tags: woodworking, saw

I'm planning to build a simple stool from pieces of 2x3 wood for the legs. It's my first foray  into woodworking as an adult so I'm trying to plan everything to aim for a decent result.

Bearing in mind I'm inexperienced with a saw and not gifted with my hands. How can I make the straightest cuts possible?

My current plan is to

1. Mark the lines to cut with a set square and sharp pencil.
2. Mount the wood to a Mitre box with a G clamp.
3. Clamp the Mitre box to an adjustable workbench.
4. Make the cuts on the 'waste side' with a tenon saw using long 'back strokes' to make each cut. Focus on elbow to make sure arm is not moving around wildly.
5. Sand down any excess with an electric sander.

Comment: Sounds like you've got it all figured out. So what's the question?

Comment: Well, I'm inexperienced so maybe there is a preferred method for newbies, or something to lower the chance of error.

Comment: A miter box is the preferred method for newbies. And remember... Always cut long. You can always remove more material, but adding material is difficult.

Comment: Ahh, reminds me of my favorite joke...I cut it twice and it was still too short.

Comment: Mark each line to cut on just prior to cutting. Each cut has width, and that'll make second, third and fourth legs shorter unless you account for that width in your marking.

Comment: I believe you will find that no matter how accurate you cut the legs, there will always be a little wobble in the stool , if it is a 4 legged stool, that there will always need to be a little adjusting after assembly. You do have the process down to yield your best result, from your process you listed.

Comment: That will work, but I'd use this as an excuse to get a power radial mitre saw.

Comment: I think this is why simple stools are built with 3 legs. Then small differences in length don't cause a wobble. Good Luck!

Answer (score 5):

One of the most important things about making a stool is getting the legs the same length.  I would suggest you modify the miter box something like this:

[image]

Keep everything square when building the stop piece.  Then when you actually go to cut the legs, butt a square end to the stop, clamp it down, and cut.  You will get three or four legs precisely the same length.

Keep the stop piece.  You can move the stop around easily, and you will use it again.

Time spent making a jig or a stop is never wasted.

Comment: I made the mirror image of a jig I wanted once. That was a waste of time.

Comment: Just rotate it through the fourth dimension and everything will turn out fine.